# ¿Cómo sé el languaje, y el software de la petición ( navegador ) en Express?

Tags: javascript, express, peticiones

Cuando hacen una petición a mi servidor creador en Express, y intento saber el languaje, y el software de el navegador, con `req.language` y `req.software` me da `undefined`

mi código actual es:

```js
app.get('/api/whoami',  (req, res, next)=> {

    let json = {"ipaddress": req.ip, "language": req.language, "software":  req.software}

    res.json(json)

    next()
})
```

para ver a más a detalle el código completo visite https://replit.com/@Michael-Liendo/boilerplate-project-headerparser

Comment: Puedes mostrar lo que te devuelve en `req`?

Answer (score 0):

Usando  `req.get('')` para obtener la información requerida.

para obtener el languaje: `req.get('Accept-Language')`
y el el software (User Agent): `req.get('User-Agent')`